# Two similar questions, one is successful the other is not

Tags: discussion

I'm having a little trouble understanding why [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840963/how-does-this-fsign-function-work) has been down voted and closed while a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828822/cant-understand-this-way-to-calculate-the-square-of-a-number) (similar in that they are both asking how a small code snippet works) is highly voted and still open?

Both questions ask what a piece of code does. Both show that they know what the code does, but is asking why it does it.

Should both questions be closed? Or should both be open?

Comment: Your quesion only lists the code and asks how it works.

Comment: Just a thought:  yours basically says, "Here's some code, how does this work?"  And the related question says, "After a little testing, I have found that between (&a)[k] and (&a)[k+1] is sizeof(a)/sizeof(int).  Why is that?"  Their question shows research, yours does not.  I don't know if their question shows 35-upvotes worth of research, but `*`shrug`*`

Comment: Perhaps it was a bit more clear in the other question that the OP knew what was happening.  Your question hid your knowledge of its functionality in a code comment (easily overlooked).  Nor did your title convey that you knew its functionality.

Comment: For me, your question about floats was obvious at first glance so it wasn't very interesting. On the other hand, the one about squaring an integer made me go, "whaaat?!?!?!" - even though I have a background in C.

Answer (score 11):

Your question just dumps a code snippet and says "explain this".  It is quite broad as it gives no indication at all as to what you understand, don't understand, and expect to be explained.

The other question provides a code snippet, explains what he *does* understand about it, and ask a *very specific question* about the code snippet.  Because of that it is very much answerable, and it is easy to determine if a posted answer actually adequately answers the question; that's not true of your question.

Comment: So the only thing my question doesn't do is shows what I understand about the code snippet?

Comment: @Soapy That's not the *only* thing it doesn't do.  It's *one* of the things it doesn't do.  I listed several others.

Comment: People sometimes think the minimum length of questions should be increased, due to the lower quality of many short questions. But the up-voted one we're referring to is a good example of why that might not be a 100% indicator.

Answer (score 6):

The successful question was easy to read, and it was easy to understand.  Even if a reader doesn't know what the answer is, they understand what the question is asking for, and why it's interesting.

Your question, on the other hand, provided a code block(a more difficult to read code block) and asked how it worked.  The explanation for what the code block actually did was in the code block itself.  It's difficult to read, and most people don't want to spend much energy to parse a question, so they downvote.

Comment: Yup; the successful question was an example of a pretty decent short question. Those are rare, but definitely happen!